# How to capture delete key press in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, keyboard-events

I want to capture delete key presses and do nothing when the key is pressed. How can I do that in WPF and Windows Forms?

Comment: Which UI framework? Winforms? WPF? ...?

Comment: plus in which context? a textbox, a form, etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad Afshari. Both in WPF and Winforms

Answer (score 31):

When using MVVM with WPF you can capture keypressed in XAML using Input Bindings.

```
            <ListView.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding COMMANDTORUN}"
                            Key="KEYHERE" />
            </ListView.InputBindings>
```

Comment: I wonder why didn't this get more upvotes: conceptually it's a much cleaner way.

Comment: I agree Vlad, this is a very clean way to do it. +1

Comment: On some components you can put the bindings right in the definition (I don't know if this is very common, or a uniquely Telerik thing): <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView" KeyDown="radGridView_KeyDown" KeyUp="radGridView_KeyUp"/>

Comment: @Jeff You'll find thats not so much binding but more code behind event handling.

Comment: Can you provide your implementation @StevenC.Britton

Comment: I didn't implement it, Eric.  I switched to using ESC instead, which is far easier and made little difference in my application.

Comment: Here is a working implementation of the delete key for future reference <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />

Comment: Except, Eric, as I said, that implementation doesn't work.  I tried it once again before writing this comment to double check, and I am right: it doesn't work.

Comment: Should work in .NET 4 and up. You can also add a Modifier e.g. CTRL like this: `Modifiers="Control"`

Answer (score 18):

For WPF add a `KeyDown` handler:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("delete pressed");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Which is *almost* the same as for WinForms:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("delete pressed");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to turn `KeyPreview` on.

If you want to prevent the keys default action being performed set `e.Handled = true` as shown above. It's the same in WinForms and WPF

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I prevent Delete action?

Comment: Good to know!  How to check to see if CTRL or SHIFT is pressed?

Comment: @Matt - look at `Keyboard.Modifiers`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about WPF, but try the `KeyDown` event instead of the `KeyPress` event for Winforms.

See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) on Control.KeyPress, specifically the phrase "The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown  and KeyUp  events."

Answer (score 2):

Simply check the `key_press` or `Key_Down` event handler on the specific control and check like for WPF:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
   e.Handle = false;
}
```

For Windows Forms:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
{
   e.Handled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the stuff mentioned above but nothing worked for me, so im posting what i actually did and worked, in the hopes of helping others with the same problem as me:

In the code-behind of the xaml file, add an event handler in the constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
public partial class NewView : UserControl
    {
    public NewView()
        {
            this.RemoveHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(NewView_KeyDown)); 
            // im not sure if the above line is needed (or if the GC takes care of it
            // anyway) , im adding it just to be safe  
            this.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(NewView_KeyDown), true);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     //....
      private void NewView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                //your logic
            }
        }
    }
```